# Enum Class Calling

Tags: c#, enums

I have created Enum class of LeaveReason in data access layer having values sick leave,planned leave or other reason now i want to call this enum class to my custom type layer but how to call it ???
    please help as i am new in c#...

here is my code looks like.....

**In Data Access layer :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sherserve.DataAccessLayer
{

    public enum LeaveReason
    {
        Sick,
        Planned,
        Other

    }

}
```

**In Data Custom Type layer :**

Now i want to access enum class which i created in data access layer in custom type layer.
You can see i have added reference of data access layer but it is showing error..

please correct this and tell me how i can call enum class in custom type layer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;
using Sherserve.DataAccessLayer;

namespace Sherserve.CustomTypeLayer
{
    public class EmployeeLeave
    {
        public LeaveReason LeaveType { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my problem is that i am un able to call enum class from data access to custom type and also i am unable to add reference of data access class to custom type...
please guide me properly..

thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting, It seems you can access the `LeaveType` property of the class,

Comment: Did you add reference to the assembly containing the enum?

Comment: Yes i have added assembly containing enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `Sherserve.DataAccessLayer` in the `Sherserve.CustomTypeLayer`. Typically the `Sherserve.CustomTypeLayer` would be a class library project that its output is a .dll file that you add to the other dataaccess layer from references -> add reference.

Comment: Mahmood Gamal thanks for your help but i have fixed my problem.
I have created enum class in custom type layer instead of data access layer and now i its working. :)